# Why HTTP server close the connection when client close only the send half of the connection?

Tags: c++, c, windows, http, network-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Winsock recv not working after shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846165/winsock-recv-not-working-after-shutdown)

I am trying to send HTTP request via WinSock2. I finally did it, however, I can't figure out why the connection will be closed when I shutdown the send half of the connection.

According to [RFC2616 sec8.1.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4):

> When a client or server wishes to time-out it SHOULD issue a graceful close on the transport connection. Clients and servers SHOULD both constantly watch for the other side of the transport close, and respond to it as appropriate.
>
> Servers SHOULD NOT close a connection in the middle of transmitting a response, unless a network or client failure is suspected.

I suppose the socket will still receive messages untill the server has nothing to send, but the server just close the connection **unexpectedly**.

[image: alt]

```
C:\Users\970067a\Desktop>gcc test.c -lWs2_32 && a
Bytes Sent: 59
Bytes received: 787
Bytes received: 222
Connection closed

C:\Users\970067a\Desktop>gcc test.c -lWs2_32 -D SHUTDOWN_SD_SEND && a
Bytes Sent: 59
Connection closed
```

Below is part of my source code:

```
...

iResult = getaddrinfo("www.google.com", "http", &hints, &result);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

...

int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

char *sendbuf = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

// Send an initial buffer
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

// shutdown the connection for sending since no more data will be sent
// the client can still use the ConnectSocket for receiving data
#ifdef SHUTDOWN_SD_SEND
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
  printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
  closesocket(ConnectSocket);
  WSACleanup();
  return 1;
}
#endif

// Receive data until the server closes the connection
do {
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0)
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
} while (iResult > 0);

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

...
```

Comment: But why this design? It's bad for persistence connection?

Comment: This [old mailing list thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg-old/2001JanApr/0037.html) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in RFC 2616 about half-closes or shutdowns. You aren't supposed to do them with HTTP.